# How to find function calls using exact number of parameter

Tags: php, regex, legacy-code

Given a system written in php 5.6 with a function declared like this:

```
function doSometing($param1 = '', $param2 = '',  $param3 = '',  $param4 = '', $param5 = '') {...}
```

I want to list all the calls using fifth parameter $param5.

Consider that uses may be with variable formats:

- Irrelevant spaces, breaklines, tabs, etc.
- Arguments passed as pure strings or variable names or any other php trick

Complex example:

```
doSometing( 'loreIpsum',$Loreipsum,  'loreipsum',
   "loreipsum", 'Target') ;
```

Maybe an IDE feature or plugin? Maybe Regexp expression (I'm newbie with it)?

Comment: If you want to include f.e. the _spread operator_ in “or any other php trick”, then you can not do this based on analysing the code alone in the first place. You’d need something that figures this out at run-time then.

Comment: It is impossible to find all instances, but using https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser you could examine the code, perhaps even report on any that use various ambiguous methods.

Comment: Regex? `doSometing` >> followed by 4 commas. Not foolproof but would find most instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I forgot to reduce the complexity of the context: It's a PHP 5.6 system: syntax features are more restricted, isn't it?

Comment: Just check where it is being called from in your IDE and then work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the tools you have at hand there are two options that I can suggest:

1.) If you are using PHPStorm, you can do the following:

- Go to the definition of your *doSomething* function and temporarily remove the fifth parameter from the function signature (or comment it out)
- Then run the following PHPStorm inspection on your code base: "PHP => Code Smells => Parameter numbers mismatch declaration" (see [image: PHPStorm Inspection Parameter numbers mismatch declaration]
- PHPStorm will show you all occurences where this problem occurred and with that the function calls where too many parameters (here 5) are passed to the function

2.) You can use a regular expression to search for specific function calls, for instance via your IDE RegEx search. But be aware that it will be rather tricky to design such a regex because your function can be called with variables, method calls on an object, strings, integers, etc.

But if you are sure that you are only passing in variables, numbers and strings it should be doable...